# Simplify fog type function chain using sympy

Tags: algebra-precalculus, computer-algebra-systems

I need to simplify some lengthy  $fog(x)$ where both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are known rational polynomial in one variable.

For e.g. $f(x) = (7x-9)/12$ and $g(x) = (2x-5)/7$. Then I would like to get a simplified rational expression of $f(f(g(f(g(g(f(x)))))))$.

I would like to do this in `sympy` if possible. Looked through `sympy` docs, but might have overlooked something related to such chained function simplification. If not possible in `sympy` then any other free CAS is preferred. The function chain is quite lengthy, hence would like to use a CAS.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [sagemath](http://cloud.sagemath.com),

```
  f(x)=12*x+10
  g(x)=12*x^2+10*x+1
  simplify(f(g(g(f(g(x)))))).show()
```

Does the job. It will be similar in mathematica.

Comment: This worked and I discovered sagemath !

Comment: @tabul, something worth trying!